# My Emacs in Windows Seven always shows startup error about warning

Tags: emacs

**EDITED 2**: This question is answered, not yet completed, but the solution presented by @vpit3833 work the way I need it. So, call emacs this way `emacs -nw --no-site-file`. This suppress the error message, and the `.emacs` still called. However, I still can not found the reason of the error anyway. Any suggestion? But not a bounty this time.

**EDITED 1**: I set a bounty to this question for anyone who can solved this problem. Because it's quite annoying when I startup Emacs, and I must load-file .emacs manually.

I use Emacs Native Windows application. It runs well. But now it will not read my .emacs, and always show error message:

```
if: Wrong number of arguments: #[(type level message &rest args) "ÄÅÆ  
##" [type message args level display-warning apply format] 6 ("c:/Development/Tools/emacs-23.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/warnings.elc" . 8481)], 2
```

Everything seems runs ok. But after I install Emacs W32, and Ergo Emacs, and uninstall both of them, now the Emacs Native Windows Applications display that error.

What's been wrong?

Comment: Appears as if Emacs W32 or Ergo Emacs is not properly uninstalling itself.  Can you post the stacktraces you would get up on starting emacs as in `emacs --debug-init` and `emacs --debug-init -q`?  The stacktraces should point to the place that is offending.

Comment: ow, okay! I will posted it here right away, as it happened only in my office workstation. Thanks!

Comment: well, no. The message show this : `if: Wrong number of arguments: #[(type level message &rest args) "ÄÅÆ 
##" [type message args level display-warning apply format] 6 ("c:/Development/Tools/emacs-23.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/warnings.elc" . 8481)], 2`

It's the same as previous :)

Comment: If you got this error on starting Emacs as in `emacs --debug-init`, it most likely means there is an `if` statement in your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` that is not properly formed.  Do you get a different error message for `emacs --debug-init -q`?

Comment: Here is the error message using `emacs --debug-init -q -nw` : `("C:\\Development\\Tools\\emacs-23.2\\bin\\emacs.exe")
if: Wrong number of arguments: #[(type level message &rest args) "ÄÅÆ 
##" [type message args level display-warning apply format] 6 ("c:/Development/Tools/emacs-23.2/lisp/emacs-lisp/warnings.elc" . 8481)], 2`

The same, isn't it? btw, in my home folder .emacs.d/ contains nothing but semanticdb and autosavelist.

And, I don't think the problem is in `.emacs` because, using `-l e:/emacs`, there's no problem.

Comment: Alright, the default.el could be having the offending `if`.  If adding `(setq inhibit-default-init t)` in your ~/.emacs stops the error message, it is default.el you need to find and fix the offending code.  Or, if in the unlikely event that it (the offending `if`) is in site-start.el, fix that file (if starting `emacs --no-site-file` stops the error, that is).  In both the cases, I don't know the path to those files on Windows systems.

Comment: Okay, you got my bounty :)
I haven't check the `(setq inhibit-default-init t)`, because .emacs itself won't be read, so I think it's useless to try it. But, the `--no-site-file` does a good job.

Anyway, where's the error source in this case?

Comment: If you want to get the bounty, maybe you should move your comment to answer section, so I can accept it as the answer :)
Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like either an error in your .emacs, or something got installed to a system config file by Emacs W32 or Ergo Emacs that is now being picked up by your native Emacs app. From the message itself, the problem is probably with a badly-formatted (if ...) statement.

You can check if the problem is with your .emacs by running Emacs with the -q option, which I guess in Windows you do from the "Run Program" option of the start menu?

```
emacs -q
```

If that works properly, the problem is in your .emacs. If you still get the problem, try

```
emacs -Q
```

which will ignore all config files on your system. If emacs -Q solves the problem, then the issue is with the system-wide config, but I'm not sure where that is in Windows.

Comment: thanks tyler. The -q doesn't work. I already temporarily move my .emacs file outside my HOME path. But the -Q solve it just fine. Now, I wonder where the system wide config that made this. Maybe it's from my user directory (which is somewhat confusing in Windows, as it always change for each version)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. What happened to me is I kept the "site-lisp" folder from EmacsW32 to keep my configurations. And the EmacsW32 **"site-start.el"** here looks like:

```
; ****** Added by emacsw32-setup-base at Mon Nov 01 16:16:09 2010
;; Add EmacsW32/lisp to load-path if found.
```

It works after I delete this specific part.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the HOME environment variable explicitly to point to your .emacs file.

I launch my Emacs from a batch on Windows or a shell script on Unix. Windows batch look like this

```
set drive=D:
set home=u:\Oleg

set emacs_home=%drive%\Soft\Emacs
set cygwin_home=C:/cygwin
set utils=%drive%\utils
set path=%utils%;%cygwin_home%\bin;%utils%\7-Zip;%utils%\gnu-win32;%utils%\putty;%path%
set temp=d:/temp/

%emacs_home%\emacs-23.2\bin\runemacs.exe --debug-init
```

This way I can easily modify HOME, PATH and other environment variables depending on computer I'm working on.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've try with `runemacs.exe` and also with `emacs.exe` (because I like to run it in `-nw` environment). Both still display the error message. 
If this is a home computer, maybe I will reinstall Windows. But this is office computer, so IT guy would dislike my alternative :)

Comment: btw, i just test the `-l` switch, so to run emacs, I use this `emacs -nw -Q -l e:\.emacs`. Well, the first thing I notice is, my emacs in that Dos Prompt, can display lightcolor (so there is lightred). This is quite a solution, altough I am not sure, wether the -Q switch is safe enough. 

Btw, I still open a bounty for this question. As I still curious of why it behave like that...

Comment: I added a bit. That emacs customization can not save my customization for future session. This is  maybe due to the fact that .emacs is not read automatically.

Comment: Have you tried to change the HOME directory? It might be just a question of permissions or something.

Comment: Already :)
Previously it's in E:\Projects, now it's in E:\.
Maybe I should try to move it to C:\xxx. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the identical problem.  Thanks **vpit3833** for helping me, at least with my problem.  EmacsW32 created a directory called **C:\site_lisp**.  It apparently doesn't remove that directory during an Uninstall.  I actually have multiple version of Emacs for Windows.  When I tried all of them, they all had the same problem described above.  I used the suggestion of doing **"emacs --no-site-file"**.  That seemed to work and indicated that there's a site file somewhere on my computer. I searched for it, discovered the site_lisp directory. Removing that directory, which wasn't there before, helped get my Emacs back in order again.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the 64-bit Emacs for Windows     (http://semantic.supelec.fr/popineau/programming-emacs.html#sec-2) and encountered this same error.  Turns out that site-lisp/site-start.el had this incorrect elisp:

```
(lwarn "Can't find %s" lisp-dir)
```

Looking at the warning.el code, this doesn't match the function parameters.  I changed the line to this:

```
(lwarn '(emacsw32) :warning "Can't find %s" lisp-dir)
```

and the load error went away.